# Displaying inaccurate date using moment.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, momentjs

Using nodejs, jade and moment.js

```
<div class="post-date"> #{entry.published_at} </div>
```

Every time user creates entry and the date published is updated. It is dynamic.

Example: Raw date shows "Thu Jan 01 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)"
On web page, converting the raw date with momentjs so only Jan 01 2015 is displayed.

Script

```
   $('.post-date').each(function(i, e) {
      var date = $(this).text();
      $(this).html(moment(date).format("DD MMMM YYYY"));
    });
```

But this displays incorrect date, for example: Jan 02 2015.

Couldn't figure why it is displaying incorrect date.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that `entry.published_at` is a `Date` object? If so, you're parsing it as a string when you are creating the `moment`.  You should just format it to begin with instead of reinterpreting it.

Comment: @MattJohnson yes it is a Date object on backend with moment js. Oh so you mean published_at should be formatted on backend?

Comment: What I mean is that you are first rending it as a string within the div tag (perhaps implicitly).  Then your jquery function is parsing that string and reformatting it with moment.  What happens if you remove the function - does it show like you showed "example raw date..."?  That's a string.

Comment: Sure - you could run moment on the back-end since it's node.  That would probably be easiest.  But if you're running it on the front-end, you need to be careful about what string is being parsed.  For example, you could call `.toISOString()` on the date on the back end, then moment could parse it up easier on the front end.

Comment: @MattJohnson - thanks so much. Got it working on front end instead of back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MattJohnson - suggested formatting the date instead of parsing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it could be because of Timezone.

Take a look into this link: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: ah it means I need to convert timezone as well?

Comment: I recommend you integrate moment.js in your server code, to render `#{entry.published_at}` as you want, before doing it at client side...
OR you could pass a JSON with Data, and then render to the template. 
I personally use [nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) as the template engine for my node.js proyects :)